# Adverbs for the verb "overlap"

Tags: adverbs

I want to say something like

> My research interest has a big overlap with professor A in area B.

by saying that

> Professor A's interest in B overlaps my interest _____

Since this will be in my personal statement, I hope to use an appropriate and formal word in _____. So far the only word I can come up with is "largely". Are there any alternatives?

Comment: "Significantly"? And I think that word order in this sentence should be different.

Comment: @zipirovich What order do you think is more appropriate? Thank you!

Comment: "Professor A's interest in B significantly overlaps my interest" or "Professor A's interest in B overlaps significantly my interest".

Comment: You're right to use his name first. Perhaps "Professor A's interest in B **mirrors my own**"

Comment: I'm wondering why the OP's time reference is the present not the simple past.

Answer (score 1):

*Mostly* would work.

> Professor A's interest in B overlaps my interest mostly.

Adverbs at the end of sentences might not get a lot of attention from a listener /reader unless they are paying close attention.  Because of this, it's best to move *mostly* a bit further up if that fact is important.

> Professor A's interest in B mostly overlaps mine.

Answer (score 0):

Although either is correct, I think I'd like the adverb before the verb.  "Professor A's research greatly overlaps my own."